# Creating a virtual Python environment in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I wanted to install a virtual environment for Python, but as far as I know, the venv folder should be created using the command python -m venv venv and then you need to run the script, but the folder is simply not created.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRyXS.png)

I created a folder on drive C and called it WEB, in it I created another directory, web_main, and I’m trying to create a directory in it, but nothing happens except the Python inscription after executing the command.
(If it’s not difficult for you, I would like to receive a detailed answer)

Comment: Have you run `ls` (or I think it's `dir` on windows, but I could be wrong)? Make sure the folder truly doesn't exist

Comment: Read [document about create virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment-in-the-terminal) can help.

Answer (score 1):

To create a `.venv` folder in vscode.

- Open vscode in a *folder*
- Install the python extension
- Use the command palette (ctrl+maj+P) and type "Python: Create environment"
- Follow the instructions (choose venv or conda, your Python, install or not a possible requirements.txt, etc)
- A `.venv` folder will be created, and the environment should be activated automatically when you open the folder with vscode (you could select the python to use at the botom right of the vscode window).

Remember to save your work and allow the Python extension a few moments to detect and set up the newly created virtual environment.

Comment: thanks for the answer, everything turned out to be simpler, I just wrote py instead of python and everything worked